# Scroll conflict for multiple CollectionView in a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have two `UICollectionView`  `collectionViewA` and `collectionViewB` in my `ViewController`, `collectionViewB` is presented as a subView when a button is tapped, the issue i have now is that when i scroll on `collectionViewB`, `collectionViewA` scrolls too, is there a way to only scroll for the active `collectionView` without affecting the second.?

```
extension TrendListVC: UICollectionViewDelegate,
        UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if collectionView == self.collectionViewForSubView{
            return count
        }
        return 60
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if collectionView == self.collectionViewForSubView{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ModalViewCell

            //let setting = settings[indexPath.item]
            //cell.setting = setting
            return cell
        }else{

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell

            cell.itemNameLabel.text = "Name".uppercased()


            return cell
        }

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {


        var reusableView : CollectionHeader? = nil

        if collectionView == self.collectionView{
            if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
                let head = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "headerCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionHeader
                head.trendListVc = self
                head.headerHeightConstraint = headerHeightConstraint
                reusableView = head
            }
        }

        return reusableView!
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if collectionView == self.collectionViewForSubView{

            if count % 2 != 0 && indexPath.item == count - 1{
                let paddingSpace = sectionInsets.left * (itemsPerRowForSubView + 1)
                let availableWidth = collectionViewForSubView.frame.width - paddingSpace
                return CGSize(width: availableWidth + 23, height: cellHeight)
            }else{

                let paddingSpace = sectionInsets.left * (itemsPerRowForSubView + 1)
                let availableWidth = collectionViewForSubView.frame.width - paddingSpace
                let widthPerItem = availableWidth / itemsPerRowForSubView

                return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: cellHeight)
            }
        }else{
            let paddingSpace = sectionInsets.left * (2 + 1)
            let availableWidth = view.frame.width - paddingSpace
            let widthPerItem = availableWidth / itemsPerRow

            return CGSize(width: widthPerItem + 4, height: widthPerItem)
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

        if collectionView == self.collectionView{
            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 50)
        }else{
            return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        }
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if collectionView == self.collectionView{
            showControllerForSetting(setting: "Name")
        }else if collectionView == self.collectionViewForSubView{
            print("Some thing")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to using your ViewController as delegate and datasource for both of your collection views. You need to create separate delegate classes for each collection view.

Comment: That's not the cause, i have a separate delegate and datasource for the two.

Comment: sorry wasn't obvious from your post

Comment: Is collection view B inside collection view A? If so you might find gestures are being applied to both.

Comment: CollectionViewB and CollectionViewA are both stand alone, i use the windowKey to present collectionViewB as a modal, let me update the code, you can full understand what am trying to do

Comment: Can't really tell what might cause it from code but if you override scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) in your delegates you should be able to tell what is setting the scroll value for collection view A. Another option might be to disable the gestures for collection view A while collection view B is displayed